# storing user data in php

Tags: php, ajax

Im new to php and im trying to do the following;
1. i have two fields (email and name)
2. i need to store both in a variable that will be exculsuvly for that user.

i have created and index.php and it pulls the head.php (it has the input fields in the head)
i'm using bootstrap so here my header form:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="notSureWhatToEnterHere" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

So obviously i dont know how to not refresh the page i just want to store the data in two variables in something like:

```
 $myemail = $_GET["email"];
 $myname = $_GET["name"];
```

i then need to vigure out how to assign each user input there own "id" so i can use that info at a later date and hopefully assign a login type of system.

Comment: i read it more as a question about sessions and db's

Comment: can you be specific to the post please..im trying to learn here. i understand ajax works great for/with this but i want to know why and how...hence the post on this site.

Comment: AJAX can bridge the gap between "client" what the user sees and "server" what goes on the background without refreshing the page as you said. You need to look into Javascript or jQuery as well to pass the variables to a PHP script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit the form via ajax (see: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and save the variables in a session variable (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) or save as a cookie (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

So you will need to create a .php file that receives the ajax call and then saves that info into a session

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

    $params = array('email', 'name');

    foreach($params as $param) { $_SESSION[$param] = $_POST[$param]; }


    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($_SESSION), ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```

Then via javascript would look something like this:

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        function navbarFormSubmit() {
            var params = $('form.navbar-form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type        : "POST",
                url         : 'http://www.pathtoyoursite.com/session.php',
                data        : params,
                dataType    : 'json',
                success     : function (resp) { console.log(resp); }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form.navbar-form').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                navbarFormSubmit();
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

As far as saving the data for later usage, you would want to use MySQL or some other database and save the form much like the session flow.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look and review PHP SESSION:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: it is highly recommended to NEVER reference w3schools: http://w3fools.com

Comment: Especially for PHP and database access.

Comment: He's a beginner so for basic idea, use w3schools

Comment: for basic idea, use manaul